# "Where" are Websocket servers hosted on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, websocket, ws

I'm trying to host a Websocket server on my heroku app. There already is a GraphQL server running, but I don't think it's the cause of my problem.
So my server is started like this

```js
const wss = new ws.Server({ port: port }, () => console.log(`Serveur WebSocket prêt ${port}`));
```

There is no error, but when I try to connect to the server in my browser, just like this :

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://ethyme-api.herokuapp.com/');
```

I get an error 404.
So my question is, what is the path of the ws server, so I can connect to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your Heroku app is called `ethyme-api` and and your locally run application is available under ws://localhost:$PORT/ the websocket will be available under `wss://ethyme-api.herokuapp.com/` and `ws://ethyme-api.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: no, here is what happens when i connect to these urls : 
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://ethyme-api.herokuapp.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Comment: When running the websocket server locally. How do you connect to it? Is it `ws://localhost:$PORT/`? Is it `ws://localhost:$PORT/somemoretext`? If it contains `somemoretext` you need to include them for the Heroku URL as well.

Comment: It's just `ws://localhost:8000`